# Como mostrar los datos de una Lista de Objetos (coleccion) en C#?

Tags: c#, lista, objeto

Me piden que cree una clase Carrera y una Atleta, y muestre cierto datos por consola. En la Clase Carrera tengo que crear un **método** que ordene a los **concursantes** de manera alfabética. Probé sacar el primero y ultimo, y esta todo bien. Mi problema viene ahora:

```
public void ordenarPorNombre()
    {
        this.Competidores.OrderBy(x => x.getNombre()).Last().DatosAtleta();
    }
```

Ahí estoy probando sacar el ultimo, y funciona, pero necesito que muestre todos en orden alfabético... Imagino que solo debo sacar el Last() y poner otra palabra que lo haga, pero nose cuál es...

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Creo que existía un `this.Competidores.OrderBy(x => x.getNombre()).All();` pero no estoy seguro. ç

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente usa Linq para ordenar y luego haz un foreach:

```
public void ordenarPorNombre()
{
     this.Competidores.OrderByDescending(x => x.Nombre).ToList().ForEach(x=>x.DatosAtleta());
}
```